# How do i get access to the container in the twig loader filesystem?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working on getting template AB Testing up and running and i need access to the container in the twig loader so that i can swap out the templates if a user is part of our AB test.  So far i've attempted:

```
twig.loader.filesystem:
    class: %twig.loader.filesystem.class%
    arguments: [%templating.locator%, %templating.name_parser%, @service_container]
```

and

```
project.components.loader.project_twig_loader:
    class: %twig.loader.filesystem.class%
    arguments: [Project\Components\Extensions\TemplatingProjectTemplateLocator, Project\Components\Extensions\Templating\ProjectTemplateNameParser, @service_container]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.loader }
```

but they just errors throw errors.

however if i remove the container and do the setup below it works however.

in my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    twig.loader.filesystem.class: Project\Components\Extensions\TwigFilesystemLoader\ProjectFilesystemLoader
```

in my file:

```
class ProjectFilesystemLoader extends \Twig_Loader_Filesystem
{
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocatorInterface
 */
protected $locator;

/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParserInterface
 */
protected $parser;

/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
 */
protected $container;

public function __construct(FileLocatorInterface $locator, TemplateNameParserInterface $parser, ContainerInterface $container)
{
    parent::__construct(array());

    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->parser = $parser;
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->cache = array();
}

protected function findTemplate($template)
{
 ...
}
}
```

so i'm lost, how do i get the container into the twig loader?

Comment: what are the errors you are getting when including the "@service_container" ?

Comment: "__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given"  It looks like the original constructor is being called and my override merely overrode the class.

Comment: why are you calling `parent::__construct(array());` ?

Comment: because the Twig_Loader_Filesystem filesystem uses it to set it's paths.
    public function __construct($paths = array())
    {
        if ($paths) {
            $this->setPaths($paths);
        }
    }

Comment: which version of symfony2 are you using?

Comment: i'm using symfony version 2.2